# Removing documents from one mongo collection that are matched in another collection

Tags: mongodb

This may be a noobie question but, how do I (efficiently) remove all documents from one mongodb collection that match documents found in another collection?  For example, using mongo shell, we could do the following:

```
   db.getCollection('coll1').find({}).forEach( function(doc) {
     db.getCollection('coll2').remove( { name: doc.name, value: doc.value } );
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to do it using $in with remove by passing array of name or Id's in $in array with remove.

```js
 db.getCollection('coll1').find({}).forEach( function(doc) {
   
   // create idsArray from the doc data and pass same in $in
   
     db.getCollection('coll2').remove({ id: { $in: idsArray });
   })
```

I hops it will help. :)

Comment: I am not sure that this helps, @Lucky.  The subsequent remove call will perform a find matching on the doc.name and doc.value which are the two fields I would like to eliminate.   I have a follow-up suggestion of my own that speeds removal.   If I create an index on `coll2` then the find operation in the remove is faster.

`db.getCollection('coll2').createIndex({ name: 1 });`